# Avoiding using "ancestor::" Xpath axis

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to find a way to rework this transform to where I do not have to use the `ancestor::` axis in my Xpath:

```
<xsl:template match="p[ancestor::p]">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except ppr" />
</xsl:template>
```

Example of source:

```
<root>
  <p>
     <p/>
     <section>
        <p/>
     </section>
     <ppr/>
     <content/>
     <p/>
     <picture/>
  </p>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
  <p>
     <section>
     </section>
     <ppr/>
     <content/>
     <picture/>
  </p>
</root>
```

I cannot use explicit Xpath or positioning to grab these `<p>` elements as their location is random and without pattern in my original source document.

The reason I'm trying to not use `ancestor::` is because the XSLT processor I'm using is taking over 30-50 seconds evaluating that Xpath expression. **I don't want this question to be about which XSLT processor I'm using or other implementations with my setup but rather focus on the question at hand: Is there any way to not use `ancestor::` in my above transform?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a requirement that you use only xslt-2.0 (the tag implies this)? The xslt tag implies that any version will work.

Comment: @Ryan Gates, sorry Ryan that is a bit misleading, this is only for XSLT-2.0.

Comment: Why not just use  `//p//p` ?

Comment: guess I should post it as answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be as simple as:

```
//p//p
```

Comment: The leading "//" is unnecessary in a match pattern: its only effect is to ensure that "p" elements are only matched if they are part of a complete document, and in your case this test is almost certainly redundant (and it will add a few microseconds).